# ASP.NET MVC Helper Extension Method not rendering text as a control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tried to create this Extension method.  Works except that the helper is rendering text, not the control to the View when the page renders:

I included using System.Web.Mvc.Html; at the top of my helper class that contains this extension method so that it would understand helper.RadioButton.

```
public static string WriteTestControlToScreen(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder();
    fields.Append("<fieldset>");
    fields.Append("     <div class='formLabel'><span class='requiredText'>*</span><label>Background Color</label></div>");
    fields.Append("     <div class='formField'>" + helper.RadioButton("rbBackgroundColorWhite", 0, false) + "<label class='fieldInlineLabel' for=''>White</label></div>");
    fields.Append("     <div class='formField'>" + helper.RadioButton("rbBackgroundColorWhite", 0) + "<label class='fieldInlineLabel' for=''>Black</label></div>");
    fields.Append("</fieldset>");

    return fields.ToString();
}
```

Output in the View then looks like this (notice it's not rendering a radiobutton but treating it as text instead):

*Background Color
<%=Html.RadioButton('rbBackgroundColorWhite', 0, false)%>White
<%=Html.RadioButton('rbBackgroundColorWhite', 0)%>Black

Comment: How are you invoking WriteTestControlToScreen?

Comment: <%= Html.WriteTestControlToScreen() %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little poking around with Reflector, and I noticed that the MVC extension methods for Input fields all use an InputHelper class, which in turn uses a TagBuilder class:

```
private static string InputHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, string name, object value, bool useViewData, bool isChecked, bool setId, bool isExplicitValue, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    ModelState state;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
    }
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
    builder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
    builder.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(inputType));
    builder.MergeAttribute("name", name, true);
    string str = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    bool flag = false;
    switch (inputType)
    {
        case InputType.CheckBox:

              //...etc.
```

What follows are several case statements covering the additional rendering required for the various input types.  But you get the point.  The folks at MVC are not concatenating strings; they are using the MergeAttribute (and other) methods to do the dirty work for them.  My guess is there is some browser compatibility goodness in there as well.

What I am suggesting is that you could use the TagBuilder class to build your HTML, just like the MVC folks do.

Comment: But in the end, aren't they just returning a string? i.e. return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

Comment: Yes, but see my second answer below.

Comment: seems like I could reuse InputHelper and just pass in the input type and its attributes to get the same effect rather than re-invent the wheel and code a method for each type of control using TagBuilder

Comment: sh**, InputHelper is private.  I'd have to copy the same damn thing into my own class or something.

Comment: But you would have to pull in TagBuilder too, and anything else it depends on. The asp.net MVC source is available at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471. I suppose you could make InputHelper public and recompile the DLL.

Comment: I'll just make my own controls.  And thanks.  Hey, tried to find InputHelper again in reflector, even tried to search.  I had it up the other day.  Is there any easy quick way to find this again.  I looked at the assemblies and weird, I just don't see it.

Comment: Nevermind, I cracked open the source and searched for it.  It's under System.Web.MVC.Html then InputExtensions

Comment: I agree, searching in Reflector is a bit hit or miss.  It finds some things but not others.  Good luck with the controls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is that you are outputting <%= %> tags at a time when MVC is expecting literal html output.  In other words, it's not processing these tags.

Consider putting your HTML in an .ASCX file and doing a [RenderPartial](http://blogs.intesoft.net/post/2009/02/renderaction-versus-renderpartial-aspnet-mvc.aspx).

Comment: but this is a helper method, are you saying put that in an .ascx?  I don't always want to use an .ascx for all my HTML though.

Comment: The problem is that MVC expects your <%= %> tags to be in the View, not in the helper method.  By the time it gets to the helper method, it's too late.  The rendering engine doesn't go through the helper method HTML looking for these tags.

Comment: You can make helper methods all you want.  You just can't put <%= %> tags in them.

Comment: how did you know this?  Just wondering how you figured that out or did you just assume that's the case based on the result?

Comment: I opened the System.Net.MVC.dll using Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). Reflector can disassemble to c# code, so I disassembled the TextBox helper extension method, and followed the method calls to InputHelper and TagBuilder.

Comment: Really?  A space fixed it?  I always put a space, but I didn't know it was required.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but there is an elegant solution that I have used when I want to render Telerik MVC controls within one another.  However, it could be used with any HTML helpers.  It involves creating an inline helper in the cshtml (for razor) file as shown below:

```
<!-- This helper avoids nested literals with the sub-panel item -->
@helper RenderPositionalResponsibilities()
{
    Html.Telerik().PanelBar()
        .Name("ContactSubItem")
        .Items(subitem =>
        {
            subitem.Add()
                .Text("Positional Responsibilities")
                .Content(
                    @<text>
                        <div class="container scrollable" style="height: 150px;">
                            @Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.IsTrue)
                        </div>
                     </text>
                )
                .Expanded(true);
        })
        .Render();
}
```

It can then be called as shown in the Content method below:

```
@{Html.Telerik().PanelBar()
.Name("pnlUserForm")
.ClientEvents(e => e.OnExpand("pnlUserForm_OnExpand").OnCollapse("pnlUserForm_OnCollapse"))
.Items(i =>
{
    i.Add()
        .Text("User Information")
        .Expanded(true)
        .Content(
            @<text>
                <div>
                    @RenderPositionalResponsibilities()
                </div>
            </text>
         )
}
.Render();
}
```

This might be a better match for users wanting to create a helper for a very specific purpose.  In addition, since you create the helper in the cshtml file (for razor), you get all of the intellisense for the controls.